# Why does a script from PSGallery not have a Zone.Identifier stream?

Tags: powershell, nuget

A NuGet repository, such as PSGallery, is clearly a remote system. Why do scripts installed from there not have a Zone.Identifier stream?

```
PS C:\> Find-Script -Repository PSGallery -Name Test-RPC | Install-Script -Scope CurrentUser

Untrusted repository
You are installing the scripts from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its InstallationPolicy value by running the
Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the scripts from 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y

PS C:\> Get-Item -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\Test-RPC.ps1 -Stream *

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\lit\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\Test-RPC.ps1::$DATA
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\lit\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts
PSChildName   : Test-RPC.ps1::$DATA
PSDrive       : C
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer : False
FileName      : C:\Users\lit\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\Test-RPC.ps1
Stream        : :$DATA
Length        : 7771
```

**The question is:**

How can I ensure that users with ExecutionPolicy of RemoteSigned will need to use the signature? How will PowerShell know it is a remote file without a Zone.Identifier stream?

Is there any reason that package providers, especially untrusted ones, should not create a Zone.Identifier stream?

Comment: `Windows determines ADS (browser-based stuff)`, not PowerShell. In the PowerShell session, the `Install` action is more `like a local copy action`, not a web download, though the actual action is getting stuff from a remote repo. The ADS is not relevant to the EP Signature requirement, via an `Install`. In a browser-file download, ADS should be removed, in virtually all cases, before a file is used or Windows will balk at it when you try to use it. Test the theory, using, a browser and saving scripts vs curl.exe/Invoke-WebRequest/Invoke-RestMethod vs the Install, etc., to grab stuff

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

```
Clear-Host 

$Url          = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Test-RPC/1.0/Content/Test-RPC.ps1'
$output       = 'C:\Temp\Test-RPC.ps1'
$ValidateFile = {
    Try {Get-Item -Path $output -Stream Zone.Identifier -ErrorAction Stop}
    Catch [System.Exception]
    {
        Write-Warning -Message 'Error'
        $PSItem.Exception.Message
    }
}


Remove-Item -Path $output -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output

Remove-Item -Path $output -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
& $ValidateFile

Remove-Item -Path $output -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)
& $ValidateFile

Import-Module -Name BitsTransfer

Remove-Item -Path $output -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output
& $ValidateFile

Remove-Item -Path $output -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Asynchronous
& $ValidateFile
# Results
<#
WARNING: Error
Could not open the alternate data stream 'Zone.Identifier' of the file 'C:\Temp\Test-RPC.ps1'.
WARNING: Error
Could not open the alternate data stream 'Zone.Identifier' of the file 'C:\Temp\Test-RPC.ps1'.
WARNING: Error
Could not open the alternate data stream 'Zone.Identifier' of the file 'C:\Temp\Test-RPC.ps1'.

WARNING: Error
JobId                                DisplayName   TransferType JobState   OwnerAccount                      
-----                                -----------   ------------ --------   ------------                      
f5f04c93-4247-4095-8d9a-587b26d64d26 BITS Transfer Download     Connecting 570A5E12-BA93-4\WDAGUtilityAccount
Cannot find path 'C:\Temp\Test-RPC.ps1' because it does not exist.
#>
```

Doing the aforementioned download using real curl.exe also does not add the internet ADS tag. Manually download curl.exe via your browser.

```
https://curl.se/windows
```

Check the ADS data, note ***the internet tag is there.***

The download using real curl.exe, in cmd.exe

```
curl.exe -O https://curl.se/windows/dl-7.76.0/curl-7.76.0-win64-mingw.zip
```

Check the ADS data, not ***the internet tag is not there.***

Lastly, as for this ...

> ***`How can I ensure that users with ExecutionPolicy of RemoteSigned`.***

***As documented and publically stated by MSFT, EP's are not a security boundary and that was never their design.***

> RemoteSigned ExecutionPolicy:
>
> • Allows scripts to run
>
> • Requires that all scripts `***downloaded from the Internet***` must
> be `***digitally signed by a publisher you specified as trusted***`.
> This includes scripts received via email and instant messaging
> platforms.
>
> • Will not require digital signing of scripts written on a local
> computer
>
> • May allow running of malicious scripts from other sources

They are there to prevent accidental code runs. ***EP's can easily be bypassed*** and that too is fully documented/demo'd

> 15 Ways to Bypass the PowerShell Execution Policy:
> https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy
>
> Detecting Offensive PowerShell Attack Tools:
> https://adsecurity.org/?p=2604

One can open any script in the ISE/VSCode, etc., select all, and hit run and the EP has no control over that. EP, is for running scripts by name, meaning, calling from the consolehost, scheduled task, etc.

Nothing stops a user from opening the script, removing the sigblock, and saving the script with a new name, and running it or creating a blank script, copy the content from the clocked script, saving and running.

PowerShell risk management/Security controls/mitigation are all the normal network/client stuff as well as all about full enterprise logging, auditing, and early alerting/effect response when strangeness is seen/discovered.

Comment: Is your answer that only web browsers create an ADS stream with Zone.Identifier. And, that even if they do, it is not really very meaningful?

Comment: ADS is just a source indicator. They have always been easily removable by anyone at any time ever since they existed. Many just did not know or pay attention to ADS, until nefarious types started using them as attack vectors, which is called `steganography`. One can virtually embed whatever I want in an ADS, with any file type, for [example and image file](https://www.zdnet.com/article/malicious-code-hidden-in-advert-images-cost-ad-networks-1-13bn-last-year), though not used much anymore. Regardless of the file type ADS should be inspected, and often removed.

Comment: There are tons of articles on ADS (what they are & why they exist) and how one should deal with them, for decades now. [Understanding & inspecting ADS Streams](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/07/introduction-to-alternate-data-streams)   ---   [Inspecting/Creating/Using and abusing ADS](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-alternate-data-streams)   ---   [Practical Guide to Alternative Data Streams in NTFS](https://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security%2Faltds)